# API to preview Facebook content before its publication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

Is there any way how to preview and test Facebook content before we will publish it? I am looking for an API method to provide this feature in our application.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about to preview an ad using API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/generatepreview/v2.9

If you are talking about to preview an ad while using Ad Manager of Facebook: you can see it there already when you do it. The preview (generated by the API above) is shown in the Ad Manager.

If you are talking about to preview a non-ad post when using Facebook: The post editing tool is WYSIWYG.